# How to remove the unselected item in a select and radio input in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

If a model's field is a choice or foreign key, the widget on the page is a select input or radios if you specify that. Django places "---------" in the first item as an unselected value. How can I override it or even remove it? I remember reading the way to do it but can't find it any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

> If the model field has choices set,
>   then the form field's widget will be
>   set to Select, with choices coming
>   from the model field's choices. The
>   choices will normally include the
>   blank choice which is selected by
>   default. If the field is required,
>   this forces the user to make a
>   selection. The blank choice will not
>   be included if the model field has
>   blank=False and an explicit default
>   value (the default value will be
>   initially selected instead).

Answer (score 8):

From the [Django forms doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/):

> By default the `<select>` widget used by `ModelChoiceField` will have a an empty choice at the top of the list. You can change the text of this label (which is "---------" by default) with the `empty_label` attribute, or you can disable the empty label entirely by setting `empty_label=None`:
>
> > `field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label=None)`

If you need to do this on a `ModelForm`, I had an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692676/modelchoicefield-removing-the-blank-choice).

Comment: Arrgghhh, the solution in the link seems too complicated. I guess in this case, better resort to ordinary form.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a ModelForm, just set `default=None` in your model, like this:

```
choose = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=choose_dict, default=None)
```

Comment: -1: `default` is used at the database level, not at the form level. This just means that if the value is not set when creating the model object, the value will be set to `None`. Dangerous advice

Comment: @Patrick not true (at least since Django 1.4). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11721969/898423

Comment: True, I've just checked the docs and it doesn't seem to be the case for the latest django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default