# Editing the emtpy_value attribute for a select widget with django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, widget, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to figure out how to set the empty value of a 'select' element to "Choose your location" instead of "--------" in django using django-crispy-forms. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out since I was using choices in a CharField, I could just add a default blank value with my label and set blank=False on my model. The answer is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739286/1124580), but it's somewhat hidden in the question, which is about ForeignKeys.