# How do I change the "no-selection" text of a Django-admin Select field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

When the Django Admin uses the Select widget, the default/top/no-selection option is "--------":

[image]

Is there a way to customize that option? I tried manually modifying the "choices" value of the Select field:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_field'].choices[0] = (u'', 'something else')
```

but that doesn't work, as the admin still displays "--------"...

***Update:***
The answers in the suggested [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739260) almost solve my problem... however, the answers there seem to be techniques for giving ALL of the Select fields the *same* no-selection option.

In my case, the ModelForm in question is used by a TabularInline ModelAdmin, so the form is repeated 20 times on the page, and different instances need a different no-selection value (that is dependent on self.instance).

Also, the most up-voted answer doesn't work with the latest version of Django - the `empty_label` field now needs to be set on the `self.base_fields['my_field']` object *before* calling `super()`.  But I need `self.instance` to exist in order to do my customizing, and `self.instance` is `None` before `super()` is called...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize/remove Django select box blank option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739260/customize-remove-django-select-box-blank-option)

Comment: @Jkdc - not quite a duplicate... I don't think... See my update, above.