# Django-filter Boolean Field with custom values

Tags: django, filter, django-crispy-forms, django-filter

After successfully implementing `crispy-forms` and `django-tables 2` it came for me to implement filtering in tables using `django-filter` and I am ripping my hair out.

First of all I find it much worse documented and probably this is why I can't find info that I need.
I would like to have a dropdown in the form with which I can select weather to show `All users`, `Superusers`, `Normal users`.
So I have moved from `BooleanFilter` to `ChoiceFilter` with custom choices.

```
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    SUPERUSER_CHOICES = {
        ('', 'All'),
        ('True', 'Superusers'),
        ('False', 'Normal users')
    }
    username = filters.CharFilter(field_name='username', lookup_expr='icontains')
    is_superuser = filters.ChoiceFilter(field_name='is_superuser', lookup_expr='exact',
                                        choices=SUPERUSER_CHOICES,)
    test = filters.Filter

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'is_superuser']
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Why are these dashes there? How to get rid of them?
Maybe I don't even need to use `ChoiceFilter` to change values of options?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `empty_label` to `None` on the `ChoiceFilter` per [the docs here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#choicefilter):

```
is_superuser = filters.ChoiceFilter(
    field_name='is_superuser', 
    lookup_expr='exact', 
    choices=SUPERUSER_CHOICES, 
    empty_label=None
)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740011/2532070) to better understand Django's `empty_label`.