# How can I modify radio button field in Django to suit my preference?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER_SELECT = (
        ('f', 'Female'),
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('o', 'Other'),
    )
    TITLE_SELECT = (
        ('0', 'Mr.'),
        ('1', 'Mrs.'),
        ('2', 'Ms.'),
        ('3', 'Mast.'),
    )
    title=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=TITLE_SELECT)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=GENDER_SELECT)
```

forms.py:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Person
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'title': forms.RadioSelect(),
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form1.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Output:

[image: Person]

As you can see, the fields display as verticals whereas I want them horizontal. Plus, I don't want that initial '__________' choice. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the dashed lines you can use the empty label attribute in your model choice field, so for example :

```
forms.ChoiceField(empty_label="(Select here)")
```

Or set it to None or empty string if you don't want anything

As for the horizontal render you can provide your own renderer so something like that would work :

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
  def render(self):
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))

  forms.ChoiceField(choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES, empty_label="(Select here)",widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer))
```

or if you are using bootstrap :

```
forms.ChoiceField(choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES, empty_label="(Select here)", attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'})
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the empty label (the dashed lines) in a `ModelForm`, configure the underlying model field so that the default value is `None`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    GENDER_SELECT = (
        ('f', 'Female'),
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('o', 'Other'),
    )
    TITLE_SELECT = (
        ('0', 'Mr.'),
        ('1', 'Mrs.'),
        ('2', 'Ms.'),
        ('3', 'Mast.'),
    )
    title=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=TITLE_SELECT, default=None)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=GENDER_SELECT, default=None)
```

Hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868776/308204 (I had a hard time finding the answer too).